# Using CoreBluetooth CBL2CAPChannel

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, l2cap

I am trying to set up some data transfer functionality, using `CoreBluetooth` `CBL2CAPChannel`, in a Swift iOS app.

My question is about the `StreamDelegate` function:

```
func stream(:handle:)
```

How am I supposed to fire it? Or when does it get fired?

The fact is, when I set up some test data ahead, in my app, to see if the information transfer is working then all is fine (the *func stream(:handle:)* is called).

- Once with: *Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable* (where I can start some data transfer)
- And at the end (usually) with: *Stream.Event.endEncountered*

But in practical terms, I want to transfer data, after the user has taken some actions. And this is where there is a problem. At this point the *func stream(:handle:)* is never called.

Why is that? What am I supposed to do?

The issue here is to know how to come (or come back) into *func stream(:handle:)* being called with *Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable*.

Comment: I don't quite follow your question.If you want to write some data you can just check the stream's `hasSpaceAvailable` property.  You can also check the number of bytes that were written - This is returned by `write` - If not all of your bytes were written you try and send the ones that weren't - first checking `hasSpaceAvailable`.  If `hasSpaceAvailable` is `false` at any point you queue your data until the delegate fires indicating that space is now available.

Comment: Yes, your comment assumes the func stream(:handle:) is called at some point, which was not the case when I wrote the post, but I found the mechanism to have ist called again. Thanks in any case.